# Temperature logging with a fixed log size? [Windows]

Tags: logs

I was thinking if there is a program for Windows which has this?

For example currently I'm using Open Hardware Monitor which works just fine but the problem is it will just keep on outputting logs until disk space runs out

What I would like is a program where you could overwrite the old logs and have a fixed log size so that this won't cause issues in case you keep the system on for long periods of time

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: The phrase you want to use is "round robbin" (or, posisbly, "circular log"); now get Googlin' :-)

Answer (score -1):

My first suggestion is to open a ticket or comment on an existing one on the Open Hardware Monitor [GitHub](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue%20is%3Aopen%20log%20size) site and hope that one of the people involved picks it up. *Remember **nobody** is getting paid for this!*

The next is to fork & download the source code from [GitHub](https://github.com/openhardwaremonitor/openhardwaremonitor) and implement it yourself, (in addition to the ticket), then contribute it back with a pull request. *It is* ***Open Source*** *after all*.